# Why is $\sum_{d \mid N} N/d ϕ(N/d) ϕ(d) = N^2 \prod_{p \mid N} (1 - 1/p^2)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the end, given the Euler totient function $ϕ$, I want to understand why:

$$ \sum_{d \mid N} (N/d) ϕ(N/d) ϕ(d) = N^2 \prod_{p \mid N} (1 - 1/p^2)$$

Do you have any hints regarding this?

**Background:**

My question has changed since first asking it, here is what is was originally about:

> Given the Euler totient function $ϕ$, is the assignment $d ↦ (N/d) ϕ(N/d) ϕ(d)$  – or equivalently $d ↦ (N/d)ϕ(N/d)$ – for divisors $d$ of $N$ multiplicative in $d$? If so, can you give me a hint on how to prove this?

I was asking this, since I’ve read in an hint to the forgoing problem in *A First Course in Modular Forms* by Diamond and Shurman that this assignment is indeed multiplicative, which I just couldn’t see.

The hint states:

> Since the summand $(N/d)ϕ(d)ϕ(N/d)$ is multiplicative in $d$, the sum is multiplicative in $N$, so it suffices to take $N = p^e$.

Now I believe the hint given to be misleading, since:

\begin{align}
12/6 · ϕ(12/6) · ϕ(6) &= 2 · 1 · 2 \\
&≠ (6 · 2 · 1) · (4 · 2 · 2)  \\
&= (12/2 · ϕ(12/2) · ϕ(2)) · (12/3 · ϕ(12/3) · ϕ(3))
\end{align}

Or else I misunderstand the hint.

By a multiplicative function I understand a function $f$ which satisfies $f(nm) = f(n)f(m)$ for coprime $m, n$.

Comment: That assignment is not multiplicative? $ϕ(12/6)·12/6 = 1·2 ≠ (2·6)·(2·4) = (ϕ(12/2)·12/2)·(ϕ(12/3)·12/3)$? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I no longer understand the question please write out exactly what it is you are being asked to prove, what is meant by multiplicitive in d? If they are asking if $\phi(\frac{n}{d_1d_2})\frac{n}{d_1d_2}\frac{n}{d_1d_2}=\phi(\frac{n}{d_1}) \phi(\frac{n}{d_2})\frac{n}{d_1}\frac{n}{d_2}$, then no, that clearly isn't true.

Comment: I know what a multiplicative function is, I don't know what it means to say its multiplicative with respect to another variable.

Comment: @Ethan For a fixed $N ∈ ℕ$, I want $f_N(d_1 d_2) = f_N(d_1) · f_N(d_2)$ to hold for coprime divisors $d_1$ and $d_2$ of $N$ when either $f_N(d) = ϕ(N/d)ϕ(d)N/d$ or $f_N(d) = ϕ(N/d) N/d$. I thought this was equivalent. Sorry if I didn’t state my question clearly enough.

Comment: It seems you dropped the subscript N from the first function on the lhs to the 2 functions on the rhs if this was intentional what is $f(m)$?

Comment: @Ethan Sorry, I dropped it, yes.

Comment: If that is your definition, then you are correct, it is not multiplicative in $d$. Which you showed in your first comment.

Comment: @Ethan I changed the question now to a clearer version and gave more background on it.

Comment: Probably it's a print error: that function is multiplicative in this sense: $(N_1N_2/d_1d_2)\phi(N_1N_2/d_1d_2)\phi(d_1d_2)=(N_1/d_1)\phi(N_1/d_1)\phi(d_1)(N_2/d_2)\phi(N_2/d_2)\phi(d_2)$.

Comment: @user54738 But this doesn’t imply that the sum is multiplicative in $N$ or does it?

Comment: @K.Stm., you should have used \frac{}{} for your fractions, as the left hand side still isn't very clear: is it *only* $\;d\phi\left(\frac Nd\right)\,$ dividing $\,N\,$ , or *also* is $\,\phi(d)\,$ in the denominator?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry and thanks, I added brackets. Only $d$ is in the denominator of $N/d$.

Comment: Moreover each $d\mid N_1N_2$ is of the form $d=d_1d_2$ with $d_i\mid N_i$.

Comment: @user54738 Doesn’t this identity only hold for pairs of coprime $d_1$, $d_2$ and $N_1$, $N_2$ such that $N_1/d_1$ and $N_2/d_2$ are coprime as well?

Comment: @ K.Stm. If $N_1,N_2$ are coprime and $d_i\mid N_i$, then $d_1,d_2$ and $N_1/d_1,N_2/d_2$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N_1,N_2$ coprime we have:

$\displaystyle\sum_{d\mid N_1N_2} \frac {N_1N_2}d \phi\Bigl(\frac {N_1N_2}d\Bigr)\phi(d)=$

$\displaystyle\sum_{d_1\mid N_1}\sum_{d_2\mid N_2}\frac {N_1N_2}{d_1d_2} \phi\Bigl(\frac {N_1N_2}{d_1d_2}\Bigr)\phi(d_1d_2)=$

$\displaystyle\sum_{d_1\mid N_1}\frac {N_1}{d_1} \phi\Bigl(\frac {N_1}{d_1}\Bigr)\phi(d_1)\sum_{d_2\mid N_2}\frac {N_2}{d_2} \phi\Bigl(\frac {N_2}{d_2}\Bigr)\phi(d_2)$

Comment: Yes, that’ll work! Many thanks.